# JS: save page animations into mp4

Tags: javascript, video

I am trying to think of a way to save a few seconds of my HTML document that has some javascript-powered animations into a mp4 video.

The only thing I could think of thus far was using a video capture program, but I don't know too much about that, and it seems it will require standalone software.

### Question

Is there any kind of library or other native javascript solution for saving a html page's javascript animations into a mp4 video file?

**Note:** It's a html document on my local machine/IDE, not published on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [rrweb](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb) which is a js library to record the interactions on the web.

> rrweb is an open source web session replay library, which provides easy-to-use APIs to record user's interactions and replay it remotely.